# d3: Plot as a cumulative graph

Tags: d3.js, graph, cumulative-line-chart

Does [d3](https://d3js.org/) have a built in method to plot a data set as a cumulative graph?

For example, if the y values are: `[2, 4, 2, 2]`, I want them to actually be plotted as: `[2, 6, 8, 10]`. Does d3 have a way to do this or would I have to traverse the data set and do this manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays for more info but I think you can use the reduce() function here.

i.e:

```
[0, 2, 4, 2, 2].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  console.log(previousValue + currentValue);//2,6,8,10
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```