# How to create a cumulative graph in R

Tags: r, cumulative-sum, cumulative-frequency, cumulative-line-chart

Is there a cumulative graph package in R? Or how might I create a cumulative graph in R? 
For example, given values of 2, 4, 2, 2, they values should be plotted as 2, 6, 8, 10 [d3 example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706870/d3-plot-as-a-cumulative-graph). Then forming a stair step pattern as with [other cumulative records](http://people.bu.edu/fabio/newpage2.htm)

Comment: `plot(cumsum(x))` ?

Comment: That will draw diagonal lines to connect the points. It's certainly close. http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/quantitative-data/cumulative-frequency-graph

Comment: This is it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098551/creating-a-cumulative-step-graph-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per `?plot.default` - there is a "stairs" plotting method, which can be combined with `cumsum()` to give the result you want I think:

```
plot(cumsum(c(2,4,2,2)), type="s")
```

[image]